# Designing Database for File Structure

Tags: sql-server-2005, asp.net-2.0

We are using file system to store files within the application. Now we change this to use SQL2K5 for storing as BLOB instead as per requirement.

Now, we need advice regarding the design for table. Obviously, it must have a folder, files within files, size, last date modified, etc., similar to file system.

I start with:

> FileID, ParentFileID, FileName, Size, LastDateModified, DateCreated, LastModifiedBy, ModifiedBy

How can this be modified to handle folders as well?

Comment: Do you want to store files, or store a facsimile of file system structure? If the latter, why?

Comment: I want to store files as well as structure like which folder is located sizing etc etc

Comment: They've already invented something for storing files and directory structure. It's called the file system. Why do you want to duplicate this? Are you going to implement security as well?

Comment: It's mainly the requirement that we need to follow by storing it directly to database.

Comment: @Jim Ferrans: Obliviously, lol, nice edit.  Freudian slip?

Comment: Also, as for my usual broken-record speech: SQL Server sucks for storing BLOBs unless you use SQL 2008's `FILESTREAM` type.  Storing entire files as BLOBs in SQL 2005 will seriously hurt performance.

Answer (score 2):

As Mitch Wheat said, there's a really good system for this already, and it's called the File System - my first recommendation would be to look at your requirements again to see if it is *actually* required.

However, you may have your reasons, so here's how i'd structure the table:

```
filesystem (
    id,        // auto increment
    type,      // flag field: 1 = file, 2 = folder, 3 = symlink, if needed (?)
    parent_id, // id of a folder
    filename,
    modified,
    created,
    modified_by,
    created_by,
    file_data    // blob
)
```

You'd need a unique index on (parent_id, filename) if you wanted to emulate a real system.

If you needed per-file permissions, I'd just duplicate the Unix approach with owner/group/everyone permissions - you'd need to track owner and group_id in that table too. Perhaps you could simplify it to owner/everyone, and you probably could just use read/write (forgoing "execute").

Comment: @nickf: For the permission, I just add another column I assume. It's contaiining permission level ?

Comment: @dewacorp: It's nowhere near that easy.  An ACL is a complex structure and you would probably need at least two separate tables for it (one for users and/or roles, one for permissions).

Answer (score 0):

Please find the modified one:

```
FileSytemObjects(
FileSystemObjectID,
ParentFileSystemObjectID,
FileSystemTypeID, --File, Folder, Shortcut
Data,
DateCreated,
LastModified,
CreatedBy,
LastModifiedBy,
IsActive
)

FileSystemSecurity(
FileSystemObjectID,
GroupOrUserID,
IsAllowFullControl,
IsDenyFullControl,
IsAllowExecute,
IsDenyExecute,
IsAllowListFolder,
IsDenyListFolder,
...
...
)
```

With IsAllowFullControl, IsDenyFullControl, IsAllowExecute, IsDenyExecute, IsAllowListFolder,
IsDenyListFolder, I know it's not an ideal of DB design BUT it's much quicker to get permission in one hit.

What do you think?